# Set the width of SIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, sialertview

How can I set the width of [`SIAlertView`](https://github.com/Sumi-Interactive/SIAlertView)? 
I tried  this for example and it only set the height not the width.

```
SIAlertView *alert = [[SIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 240, 100)];
```

And I also tried to set it when it fires SIAlertViewWillShowNotification like below

```
- (void)SIAlertViewWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    SIAlertView *alertView = (SIAlertView *)notif.object;
    NSLog(@"alert view %@ ", alertView);
    CGRect f = alertView.frame;
    f.size.width = self.size.width * 0.62;
    alertView.frame = f;        
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:SIAlertViewWillShowNotification object:alertView];
}
```

Both won't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frame of the alert is statically set using `CONTAINER_WIDTH` (in `validateLayout`). You would need to edit this to replace the constant with a variable that you could set.